# What is the difference between a builtin command and one that is not?

Tags: bash, shell, utilities, shell-builtin

Is there any intrinsic difference between a builtin command and another command which can nominally do the same thing?

eg. Do builtins get "special" treatement? ... is there less overhead running them? .. or are they just simply 'built in'; like the dashboard of your car?

...and is there a definitive (current) list of these builtins?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

From your comments, you seem to be confused about exactly what a *shell* is.  The kernel is responsible for managing the system.  It's the part that actually loads and runs programs, accesses files, allocates memory, etc.  But the kernel has no user interface; you can only communicate with it by using another program as an intermediary.

A shell is a program that prints a prompt, reads a line of input from you, and then interprets it as one or more commands to manipulate files or run other programs.  Before the invention of the GUI, the shell was the primary user interface of an OS.  On MS-DOS, the shell was called `command.com` and people wouldn't usually change it.  On Unix, however, there have long been [multiple shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) that users could pick from.

They can be divided into 3 types.  The Bourne-compatible shells use the syntax derived from the original [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell).  C shells use the syntax from the original [C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell).  Then there are nontraditional shells that invent their own syntax, or borrow one from some programming language, and are generally much less popular than the first two types.

A built-in command is simply a command that the shell carries out itself, instead of interpreting it as a request to load and run some other program.  This has two main effects.  First, it's usually faster, because loading and running a program takes time.  Of course, the longer the command takes to run, the less significant the load time is compared to the overall run time (because the load time is fairly constant).

Secondly, a built-in command can affect the internal state of the shell. That's why commands like `cd` *must* be built-in, because an external program can't change the current directory of the shell.  Other commands, like `echo`, might be built-in for efficiency, but there's no intrinsic reason they can't be external commands.

Which commands are built-in depends on the shell that you're using.  You'll have to consult its documentation for a list (e.g., `bash`'s built-in commands are listed in [Chapter 4 of its manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html)).  The `type` command can tell you if a command is built-in (if your shell is [POSIX-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)), because POSIX requires that `type` be a built-in.  If `which` is not a built-in in your shell, then it probably won't know about your shell's built-ins, but will just look for external programs.

Answer (score 43):

There are three levels of built-in utilities:

- [Some utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/sbi.html) are really part of the shell as a programming language, even though they are not [reserved words](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_04). They are control flow utilities (`.`, `:`, `break`, `continue`, `return`, `trap`, `exit`, `exec`, `eval`), parameter-related utilities (`set`, `unset`, `shift`, `export`, `readonly`, `local`¹, `typeset`¹), alias utilities (`alias`², `unalias`²) and `times`³. These [**special built-ins**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14) get special treatment:

  - If you pass the wrong arguments to a special built-in, the shell itself may abort, rather than just skipping to the next command after displaying an error message.
  - The pre-assignment syntax `foo=bar utility` has a different meaning: it's an ordinary parameter assignment (i.e. equivalent to `foo=bar; utility`), instead of assigning to the environment for the duration of the utility only.
- Some utilities **need** to be implemented inside the shell because they act on the shell's internal settings. This includes:

  - utilities that act on the shell's current directory such as `cd`, `dirs`, `pushd`, `popd`;
  - job control utilities such as `bg`, `disown`, `fg`, `jobs`, `wait`;
  - utilities that read or manipulate other shell attributes such as `builtin`, `command`, `hash`, `read`, `type`, `ulimit`, `umask`;
  - utilities related to interactive features, when they're present, such as `fc`, `history`, `bind`.
- Some utilities are typically implemented as built-ins purely for **performance**: `echo`, `printf`, `test`, `true`, `false`.

Advanced shells such as [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands), [ksh](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh-man.html#Built-in%20Commands) and [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html) typically have more built-ins, often to implement non-standard features (usually for interaction). The manual of each shell will tell you what commands are built-in, though some shells ([zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html), at least) support dynamically-loadable modules that can provide more built-ins.

¹  <sub>Unknown to POSIX, but special in ksh and several other shells.</sub>
²  <sub>Ordinary in POSIX, but special in ksh and several other shells.</sub>
³  <sub>In `ksh`, `times` is a wrapper around the [`time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/time.html) keyword: it's an alias for `{ { time;} 2>&1;}`. Note that POSIX allows `time` to be an external utility with ordinary parsing or a keyword that applies to a whole pipeline (which it is in ksh, bash in zsh).</sub>

Comment: These distinctions are the really important ones.

Comment: Quick question, so what does "ordinary parameter assignment" mean when we do `while IFS=  read -r line` ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy `read` is not a special builtin, so `IFS=read` sets the variable only for the duration of the command.

Answer (score 11):

A builtin is a command provided by the shell, rather than by an external program.
Here are the lists for [`bash`'s builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) (they are also listed in the bash man page) and [`zsh`'s builtins](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=zshbuiltins). `ksh` provides a list by running `builtin`.

To know if a particular command is a builtin, you can run `type command`. Try `type for` and `type ls` to see this.

Comment: `type` seems to do the trick; thanks for that... but I still wonder what "provided by the shell" means... Perhaps I need to more fully understand how the *shell* relates to the kernel.... but not at 2 AM.. I'll come back to this tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

Every distro and shell has a different collection of commands vs builtin shell functions. Generally the idea is that shells build-in the most common and simple functions to save time, speed, and integrate will with the rest of their feature set. The overhead is much lower since it doesn't have to launch another system process. However it is possible to mix and match. You might run one shell that has a buildin for something, but have that command on your system too. Usually the builtin would take priority, but you could control that.

You can easily find out whether a specific command is a builtin or not by running `type mycommand`. Most shell man pages also have a list of their builtins.

**Edit:** Use `type` to find out whether a command is a builtin, and if not `which` to learn where it will be executed from.

Comment: @Caleb: thanks for your comment, but it leaves me wondering about what exactly a "system process" is.. I keep seeing references to then but I don't understand whwere the distinction lies.... (btw I can't see how 'which' is an absolute indicator).. eg..'which echo`=>"/bin/echo" and `type echo`=>"echo is a shell builtin", but 'which dd`=>"/bin/dd" and `type dd`=>"dd is /bin/dd" ...  so, I'm part way there ....

Comment: "System procses" just means it is being started up as an independent application managed by the kernel. The alternative in the case of builtins is just running a sub-function in the already running code of your shell. In the example you give, `type` is the better indicator of what is being run, but you notice `echo` is both a builtin and there is an application with that name. If your shell didn't have a builtin the system one would get run.

Comment: `which` is not necessarily a built-in command, and if it's not, it won't know about the shell's built-ins.  POSIX requires that `type` be a built-in command, so it always knows about built-ins.

Comment: Many systems ship with an alias of `which` to `type` or some set of options e.g. `alias which='type -path'` - this could be the source of confusion.

Comment: `type which` *which is /usr/bin/which* .. `which which` which is hashed (/usr/bin/which)` .. `type type` *type is a shell builtin* ..  I'm not sure what that last one means, but it looks interesting :) .. `which type` returned nothing..

Comment: I can't upvote this, until `which` is replaced by `type`. I used which, over and over again, not knowing of `type` and was very astonished to lern, that `which` is only right, if deciding between programs.