# Failed to source a adding PATH in ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash

I'd like to set a specified path to $PATH,

I write it to the top of `.bashrc`

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH
```

and activate it

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

It works

```
/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:/Users/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

Nonetheless, when I open a new terminal, it's gone.

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

As a test, I closed all the terminals and restart fresh

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

The path `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` is not there.

I checked my operations:

```
1. put desired path to the top
2. export it 
3. source to activate it.
```

What's wrong with my operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Terminal app (as well as iTerm) on macOS (which I believe that you are using) starts a *login* shell by default.  When `bash` is started as a login shell, it reads your `~/.bash_profile` file, but not `~/.bashrc`.

You may change the way that your terminal starts the shell in the terminal's preferences, or you may make your `~/.bash_profile` source the `~/.bashrc` file by adding the following to `~/.bash_profile` (probably at the end of the file):

```
if [[ "$-" == *i* ]] && [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

This would make the login shell also read the `~/.bashrc` file if it is an interactive shell and if `~/.bashrc` exists.

As an alternative, you may obviously just add the modification to `PATH` in `~/.bash_profile` instead.  I believe macOS does not install a default `~/.bashrc` file in users' home directories.

Related:

- [Why are interactive shells on OSX login shells by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119627/why-are-interactive-shells-on-osx-login-shells-by-default)
- [What is the difference between interactive shells, login shells, non-login shell and their use cases?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/what-is-the-difference-between-interactive-shells-login-shells-non-login-shell)