# How do you time how long a command took to run?

Tags: bash, date, time

How would you find out how long a running process took to complete?

Example:

```
 date; dd bs=1m if=/foo of=bar; date
```

^This example only has 1 second of resolution.

Any shell is acceptable.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

use `time`:

```
$ time somecommand --with=somearguments
```

`time` will execute the rest of the command line (in this example `somecommand --with=somearguments` ) and when the command is done it will print the elapsed time.

example output:

```
$ time somecommand --with=somearguments
...
... (output of somecommand)
...
real    0m5,020s
user    0m0,010s
sys     0m0,010s
```

the information that you typically want is `real`. in this example the command took about 5 seconds. for more information about the other numbers see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1

---

the example output above is from the bash builtin. `time` is a builtin command in most shells. there is also the system `time`. it has a different output format but otherwise behaves mostly the same as the shell builtin.

to use the system command you do it like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time somecommand --what=islove
```

or

```
$ env time somecommand --baby=donthurtme
```

there are more but that is outside the scope of this question and answer.

example output using system `time`:

```
$ env time somecommand --donthurtme=nomore
...
... (output of somecommand)
...
0.00user 0.01system 0:06.02elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3656maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+1089minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

the information that you typically want is `elapsed`. in this example the command took about 6 seconds. for the meaning of the other numbers i have not found a good explanation in the internet. you have to read the man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html

for more information about the difference of a shell builtin and a system command see here: [What is the difference between a builtin command and one that is not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not)

for more info how to invoke system command see here: [Use system command instead of Bash builtin without specifying the full path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242551/use-system-command-instead-of-bash-builtin-without-specifying-the-full-path)

---

the system time is more flexible in output. here some demonstration

you can change the output of the system `time`. for example use `-p` to get output similar to the shell builtin `time`:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -p somecommand --what=isyourname
...
real 0:06.02
user 0.00
sys 0.01
```

or use `-f` to write your own format:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %E somecommand --what=isyourquest
...
0:06.02
```

`%E` is the "elapsed" part. the part you are usually most interested in.

for completeness: you can also change the bash builtin `time` output format by changing this variable: `TIMEFORMAT`. more info: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-TIMEFORMAT

---

how to redirect or capture the output

for demonstration observe command `hellostdoutstderr`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 0.5
echo "hello out"
echo "hello err" >&2
```

example invocations:

```
 $ ./hellostdoutstderr 
hello out
hello err
```

capture stdout and stderr separately

```
$ ./hellostdoutstderr >stdoutfile 2>stderrfile

$ cat stdoutfile
hello out

$ cat stderrfile
hello err
```

the system `time` prints to stderr so it is captured with the stderr redirect

```
$ /usr/bin/time ./hellostdoutstderr >stdoutfile 2>stderrfile

$ cat stdoutfile
hello out

$ cat stderrfile
hello err
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.50elapsed 1%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3672maxresident)k
0inputs+16outputs (0major+311minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

you can tell the system `time` to print to a separate file

```
$ /usr/bin/time -o timeoutfile ./hellostdoutstderr >stdoutfile 2>stderrfile

$ cat stdoutfile
hello out

$ cat stderrfile
hello err

$ cat timeoutfile
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.50elapsed 1%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3676maxresident)k
0inputs+16outputs (0major+309minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

note that the bash builtin `time` always prints to the terminal even if stdout and stderr is redirected. this is possible because it is a builtin and can do whatever it likes (in the shell)

```
$ time ./hellostdoutstderr >stdoutfile 2>stderrfile

real    0m0,511s
user    0m0,005s
sys 0m0,006s
```

in this example stdout and stderr are both redirected to file. but bash builtin `time` still prints to terminal.

with tricks it is still possible to capture the output of the bash builtin. but why fight bash if it is easier to use system command. if you are so inclined here is more info: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-time-command-examples-usage-syntax/

---

to time more complex commands you have severals options

if you just want to time two command one after the other

```
$ time { command1 ; command2 ; }
```

also works with pipe

```
$ time { command1 | command2 ; }
```

for more complex stuff

```
$ time sh -c ' complex command chain '
```

but mind the quoting and other shenanigans. better put the commands in a script and time the script:

```
$ time ./script.sh
```

---

TL;DR: add `time` before your command. if you want to measure time inside a script use `/usr/bin/time`.

Comment: Note that \ is a shortcut version of the `command` function of bash, so `command time longrunningcommand --pedantic-comments` is the same :)

Comment: Additionally you can do `time { command; command2; }`

Comment: I dont get it, what are the comments for? what is the output of this function?

Comment: I'm with @j0h -- how do you actually use this? You've shown how to invoke it, but not how to acquire the result. (Experimentally, I've determined that the result is printed to stdout _if_ the command has no output of its own, but what if it does?) And what are the meanings of `--getsomecoffee` and `--callmom`? Does this somehow label the thing being timed? This answer needs improvement. (And yes, I'm aware two years have gone by.)

Comment: i elaborated the answer. now give me upvotes. sweet sweet upvotes.

Comment: Is it possible to execute time-command with every command I type