# Use system command instead of Bash builtin without specifying the full path

Tags: bash, shell-builtin

I use Bash as my interactive shell and I was wondering if there was an easy way to get Bash to run a system command instead of a shell builtin command in the case where they both share the same name.

For example, use the system `kill` (from `util-linux`) to print the process id (pid) of the named process(es) instead of sending a signal:

```
$ /bin/kill -p httpd
2617
...
```

Without specifying the full path of the system command, the Bash builtin is used instead of the system command. The `kill` builtin doesn’t have the `-p` option so the command fails:

```
$ kill -p httpd
bash: kill: p: invalid signal specification
```

I tried the answers listed in [Make bash use external `time` command rather than shell built-in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86266/make-bash-use-external-time-command-rather-than-shell-built-in) but most of them only work because `time` is actually a shell **keyword** – not a shell **builtin**.

Other than temporarily disabling the Bash builtin with `enable -n kill`, the best solution I’ve seen so far is to use:

```
$(which kill) -p httpd
```

Are there other easier (involve less typing) ways to execute an external command instead of a shell builtin?

Note that `kill` is just an example and I’d like a *generalised* solution similar to the way that prefixing with the `command` builtin prevents functions which have the same name as an external command from being run. In most cases, I usually prefer to use the builtin version as it saves forking a new process and some times the builtin has features that the external command doesn’t.

Comment: Enclosing `which kill` in backticks (can't put them in comments) is *slightly* shorter.

Comment: @abligh Good point. I've spent years training myself to use the "new"er syntax for command substitution.:)

Comment: @abligh: FYI, you can put \`backticks\` into comments by preceding them with backslashes (\\).  But there are reasons to stick with `$(…)` — see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778), [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147838), and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104119).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming `env` is in your path:

```
env kill -p http
```

`env` runs the executable file named by its first argument in a (possibly) modified environment; as such, it does not know about or work with shell built-in commands.

This produces some shell job control cruft, but doesn't rely on an external command:

```
exec kill -p bash &
```

`exec` requires an executable to replace the current shell, so doesn't use any built-ins. The job is run in the background so that you replace the forked background shell, not your current shell.

Comment: `env` is clearly the right answer IMHO.

Comment: @abligh: You're right in comment in my deleted answer. `command -p cmd` calling external command in `zsh`, not `bash`.

Comment: `(exec kill -p http)` causes the job to replace a sub-shell instead of your current shell and you don't have to deal with the job control cruft.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan Indeed, but `env` also doesn't know about shell builtins, since it's not a shell. You'd get the same effect with `nice` or `xargs` or any other program like that.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do what you want might be to put the line

```
alias kill="/bin/kill"
```

into your `~/.bashrc` file.  After that, each new login/invocation of bash will interpret "kill" as `/bin/kill`.

Comment: I had already thought of an alias and that was one of the solutions listed in the question I linked to but I’m hoping for a more generalised solution (similar to the `command` solution) rather than create a separate alias for each “shadowed” command. I’ve now edited my question to make this clearer and more explicit. In most cases, I usually prefer to use the builtin version as processes can be specified by job IDs. Thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a solution that requires some typing and you want a solution that requries less typing, build it:

```
runFile() { local cmd="$1"; shift; cmd="$(which "$cmd")" && "$cmd" "$@"; }
```

Abbreviating stuff that normally takes some effort is what computers excel at.

Comment: That's a good general point so I'll upvote your answer. Over the past few years, I've built up a collection of aliases, functions and scripts for the systems that I regularly use. However, I prefer to use non-customised solutions where possible as I sometimes have to work on fresh installs or servers that I didn't set up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this very specific case, the command `pgrep` is an exact match for the need.

In a general sense, a function works. From "file command":

```
fcmd(){ local a=$1; shift; $(which "$a") "$@"; }
```

call as

```
fcmd kill -p httpd
```

But if you need less typing, there is no shorter way than a good alias.

From the concept "list pid" (lp):

```
alias lp='/bin/kill -p'
```

then, just type:

```
lp httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

(In zsh) You can prefix any command name with an = sign to get the system version instead of a builtin. This is also a handy way to dodge any aliases that mess up a specific scenario.

```
$ =kill -p httpd
```

Comment: I tried that with Bash version 4.3.30 and it didn't work. I've never seen such syntax before; can you add a link to where this feature is documented? I'd normally prefix an alias with a backslash to run the non-aliased version  of a command.

Comment: @Anthony maybe this is a `zsh` only thing. I use it regularly but I'll check on `bash` from a computer tomorrow.

Comment: I suspected it might be some shell that I'm not familiar with (I’m only familiar with bash, dash and csh). There was another answer (since deleted) that only worked for `zsh`. While I tagged this question with `bash` and used it in the title, you should keep this answer as a zsh user would still find it useful.

Answer (score -2):

You could send a bugreport against your `kill` manpage and ask why this includes non-standard options that are taken from `pkill` and use `pkill` whenever you like to get the features from `pkill.`

If you call:

`pkill httpd`

you avoid the problems you describe.