# Why is my program called "set" not being executed?

Tags: shell, path, shell-builtin

I've created a simple C program like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 5) {
       fputs("Not enough arguments!\n", stderr);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

And I have my PATH modified in *etc/bash.bashrc* like so:

```
PATH=.:$PATH
```

I've saved this program as set.c and am compiling it with

```
gcc -o set set.c
```

in the folder

```
~/Programming/so
```

However, when I call

```
set 2 3
```

nothing happens. There is no text that appears.

Calling

```
./set 2 3
```

gives the expected result

I've never had a problem with PATH before and

```
which set
```

returns `./set`. So it seems the PATH is the correct one. What's is happening?

Comment: It is relatively dangerous to add '.' to your PATH. Better to just use ./ when executing something from the local directory, or move the executable into a well known directory like ~/bin/

Comment: It is also a bad idea to call your test program `test` for basically the same reason; `test` is a shell built-in too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And yet for quick tests calling a program `test` seems to make sense. Of course by the time you put it in your `PATH` you really should have come up with a different name. And until you put the program in your `PATH` you'd have to invoke it as `./test` anyway. So it is kind of OK to use the name `test` for a program as long as it is a quick test which you intend to delete before the end of the day.

Comment: @kasperd: As far as I'm aware, the conventional name for a quick test program is `foo`.

Comment: If you name it `ls` then whenever you go to see if it exists it will run (but only if you modify your path as you did in the question).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Instead of using `which`, which [doesn't work when you need it most](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then), use `type` to determine what will run when you type a command:

```
$ which set
./set
$ type set
set is a shell builtin
```

The shell always looks for builtins before searching the `$PATH`, so setting `$PATH` doesn't help here.

It would be best to rename your executable to something else, but if your assignment requires the program to be named `set`, you can use a shell function:

```
$ function set { ./set; }
$ type set
set is a function
set ()
{
    ./set
}
```

(That works in `bash`, but other shells like `ksh` may not allow it. See mikeserv's answer for a more portable solution.)

Now typing `set` will run the function named "set", which executes `./set`. GNU `bash` looks for functions before looking for builtins, and it looks for builtins before searching the `$PATH`. The section named "COMMAND EXECUTION" in the bash man page gives more information on this.

See also the documentation on `builtin` and `command`: `help builtin` and `help command`.

Comment: You recommend `type` over `which`, but don't give any reason why.  ([I know why](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10529/2421), but somebody who needs the recommendation wouldn't.)

Comment: @cjm Here's a whole treatise on *why not which*: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: Very informative. You'd never guess there's so  much controversy over such a seemingly simple command that does a simple task

Comment: @GaneaDanAndrei Mainly, use `type` instead of `which`, don't name your program "set", and realize that `function set { ./set; }` is an ugly hack that you should probably avoid.

Answer (score 11):

`set` is a builtin in bash (and probably most other shells). This means that bash will not even search the path when looking for the function.

As a side remark, I would strongly advise against adding `.` to the path for security reasons. Imagine for example `cd`ing out of `/tmp` after any other user added an executable file `/tmp/cd`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a stupid idea that my teacher forces on us in order to ,,not look unprofessional whilst presenting a program". He grades you down if it isn't done.

Comment: Brownie points for great teachers :(

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in, so the example won’t work for the same reason as with `set`.

Comment: Using `./foo` to invoke a program *is* professional; it shows that you understand why `.` should not be in $PATH.  Your teacher is wrong, and you may tell him I said so.

Answer (score 10):

`set` isn't *just* a builtin, it is a *POSIX special builtin*. There are a few builtin commands which are standards-specified to be found in a command search before anything else - `$PATH` is not searched, function names are not searched, and etc. Most builtins which are *not* *special* are actually *required* by the POSIX standard to be found in your `$PATH` *before* the shell will run any of its own builtin procedures. This is true of `echo` and most others *(though whether the standard is honored in this respect has been a matter of contention at the open group mailing lists in the past)*, but *not* of `set`, `trap`, `break`, `return`, `continue`, `.`, `:`, `times`, `eval`, `exit`, `export`, `readonly`, `unset`, or `exec`.

All of these are reserved names of the shell, and they have special attributes other than their order of preference for command search as well. For example, you cannot define a shell function with any of those names in a standards-compliant shell. This is a *good thing* - it enables people to write portable scripts *safely*. These are baseline commands from which an experienced script-writer can establish a secure and reliable foothold in his or her environment. Invading this namespace is *not* advisable.

However, if you do desire to invade it, you can do so portably with `alias`. The order of shell *expansion* enables this work-around. Because the `alias` is expanded while the command is being read, whatever you replace the `set` name with in your definition will expand correctly, it just probably should not expand to one of those names.

So you could do:

```
alias set=./set
```

...which will work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `set` is a shell builtin and the best solution would be to **use a different name** for your executable program.

Incidentally, last week, I asked a question on how to [run system commands instead of shell builtins with the same name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242551/use-system-command-instead-of-bash-builtin-without-specifying-the-full-path) and the solution I accepted was to run the command through `env`:

```
env set 2 3
```

For this particular case, where you already know that the command you want to use is located in your current directory, it would be better to directly run the executable by entering its path (using `.` to represent the current working directory):

```
./set 2 3
```

Both the above solutions are shell agnostic, i.e., they will work regardless of which shell you’re using.

Suggestions such as using the `command` builtin won’t work in Bash: this only prevents shell *functions* from being run. While, it’s not documented, I’ve also noticed that using `command` also suppresses shell *keywords*.  However, it won’t do the same for shell **builtins** such as `set`. As I understand it, `command` may work with other shells such as zsh.

Also, tricks such as `\set` or `"set"` or `'set'` don’t work for Bash builtins – though they are useful for running executable files instead of *aliases* or shell *keywords*.

*Note: This answer originally began as a comment on Eric’s (accepted) answer but grew too big to fit into a comment.  The other answers recommending the use of `type` and not adding `.` to the PATH are good ones.*