# Is it possible to strace the builtin commands to Bash?

Tags: bash, debugging, strace

Inspired by this question, titled: [When are the built-in commands loaded to memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90648/when-are-the-built-in-commands-loaded-to-memory), while attempting to answer this I tried the following command and was a bit surprised that I couldn't run it:

```
$ strace cd $HOME
```

Is there a method I can make use of to run strace for the builtin commands to Bash?

Comment: Why do you think it's surprising that a `strace` of not running a program doesn't result in a trace?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you think about how `strace` works then it makes total sense that none of the builtins to Bash would be traceable. `strace` can only trace actual executables, whereas the builtins are not.

For example, my `cd` command:

```
$ type cd
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    builtin cd "$@";
    local result=$?;
    __rvm_project_rvmrc;
    __rvm_after_cd;
    return $result
}
```

#### Trick for strace'ing cd?

I came across this technique where you could invoke `strace` on the actual `bash` process and in so doing, indirectly trace `cd` that way.

#### Example

```
$ stty -echo
$ cat | strace bash > /dev/null
```

Which results in me being able to strace the `bash` process as follows:

```
....
getegid()                               = 501
getuid()                                = 500
getgid()                                = 501
access("/bin/bash", X_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=940312, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 500
getegid()                               = 501
getuid()                                = 500
getgid()                                = 501
access("/bin/bash", R_OK)               = 0
getpgrp()                               = 32438
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x43e360, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e7233140}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x34e7233140}, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=62265}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0 (flags O_RDONLY)
fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0,
```

This is the Bash prompt, where it's sitting there, waiting for some input. So let's give it the command `cd ..`:

```
read(0, "c", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "d", 1)                         = 1
read(0, " ", 1)                         = 1
read(0, ".", 1)                         = 1
read(0, ".", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "\n", 1)                        = 1
stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/saml", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=32768, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/saml/tst", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/saml/tst/90609", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/saml/tst/90609", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chdir("/home/saml/tst")                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0,
```

From the above output, you can see where I typed the command, `cd ..` and hit enter, (`\n`). From there you can see that the `stat()` function was called, and that afterwards Bash is sitting at another `read(0..` prompt, waiting for another command.

Answer (score 8):

To `strace` the shell doing `cd /some/dir`:

```
{ strace -p "$$" & sleep 1; cd /some/dir; kill "$!"; }
```

Comment: Why the `$1` here, for `bash`, should this not be `%` or `%1`?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following:

```
strace bash -c <command/builtin>
```

For example:

```
strace bash -c 'cd /path/to/destination/'
```