# strace works for some builtin commands

Tags: kernel, process, strace, shell-builtin

I'm trying to understand some kernel level concepts in Linux. I was checking on the difference between *shell builtin* commands and the other executable commands.

[This wonderful answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11465/47538) clearly tells the difference and also specifies the need for shell builtin commands.

Now I know that using `type <command-name>`, I could check if it is an external or shell builtin command.

So I decided to do some `strace`'ing on the various commands to understand more of the internals.

I learned [this neat little trick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90713/47538) to do `strace`'es on shell builtin commands. I was able to do `strace` on `cd ..` as well according to the above answer.

Now when I run `type pwd` and get the output as, `pwd is a shell builtin`. So, I expect that I wouldn't be able to run `strace` on it, since it too is a shell builtin. But when I did an `strace` on it, I was surprised to see that `strace` worked without the need to do `stty`.

I verified `strace` for `echo` as well and it worked fine too.

So my understanding is, that `strace` worked in the case of `pwd` and `echo` because the execution of `pwd` and `echo` did not change any of the shell's behavior.

Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: Many of the commands are available as built-ins and as standalone executables. `echo` and `pwd` are 2 such commands, so you're stracing the standalong counterparts and not the built-ins when you did the above tests.

Comment: @slm, thanks. I realized after I found that I could find the type of command using `type -a`.

Comment: @slm, so if I create a standalone for cd and do the `strace`, chances are that `strace cd` will work without `stty`. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, if you have an executable, then you can `strace` it. But aliases and functions etc. are built into Bash and cannot be straced, since you'd have to `strace` Bash itself to watch them.

Comment: Re-read the man page for `strace`. There are no system calls to trace for a builtin since it's doing everything internal to Bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `pwd` or `echo` have external commands with the same name, `/bin/pwd` or `/bin/echo`. If you look at `strace` output, you can see:

```
$ strace pwd
execve("/bin/pwd", ["pwd"], [/* 68 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x241e000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f80c31b9000
```

A note that when searching in `PATH`, `strace` accepts only regular file with execute bits set.

Comment: thanks but `type pwd` gives me it as shell builtin.

Comment: @Ramesh: Use `type -a pwd` will give you a full output.

Comment: great. So if we have an `alias` or `function` along with a `shell builtin`, in those cases, `strace` might work. Am I right in my understanding?

Comment: @Ramesh: No, `strace` doesn't work with alias, or function.