# Is there a difference between read, head -1, and sed 1q?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, head, read

The following commands seem to be roughly equivalent:

```
read varname
varname=$(head -1)
varname=$(sed 1q)
```

One difference is that `read` is a shell builtin while `head` and `sed` aren't.

Besides that, is there any difference in behavior between the three?

My motivation is to better understand the nuances of the shell and key utilities like `head,sed`. For example, if using `head` is an easy replacement for `read`, then why does `read` exist as a builtin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither efficiency nor builtinness is the biggest difference. All of them will return different output for certain input.

- `head -n1` will provide a trailing newline only if the input has one.
- `sed 1q` will always provide a trailing newline, but otherwise preserve the input.
- `read` will never provide a trailing newline, and will interpret backslash sequences.

Additionally, `read` has additional options, such as splitting, timeouts, and input history, some of which are standard and others vary between shells.

Comment: Thanks. These behavior differences are what I was looking for. I also like knowing that, as @glenn-jackman pointed out, that `read` can parse parameters separated by the internal field separator `$IFS`. @ramesh's `strace` trick is also an awesome way to analyze differences.

Answer (score 6):

For one thing, you can parse text with read, not just take a whole line

```
echo "foo:bar:baz" | {
  IFS=: read one two three
  echo $two
}
```

Comment: You don't parse it with `read`, exactly, you parse it with `$IFS`. `IFS=:; set -- ${0+foo:bar:baz}; echo "$2"` accomplishes the same - and it requires no `|pipes` or cloned subshells. Or: `IFS=:; printf %.0s%s%.0s\\n ${0+foo:bar:baz}`. Else:  `echo foo:bar:baz | { IFS=:; set -- $(cat); echo "$2"; }` if you must have the pipe. In any case, the splitting is a result of your setting `$IFS`; not necessarily that you `read` it.

Comment: True. `read` assigns the split parts to variables.

Answer (score 6):

Builtins are present as a way to have the system calls more faster. So, I believe `read` command is present as a builtin to be more efficient.

Quoting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24706709/1742825),

> These builtin commands are part of the shell, and are implemented as
>   part of the shell's source code. The shell recognizes that the command
>   that it was asked to execute was one of its builtins, and it performs
>   that action on its own, without calling out to a separate executable.
>   Different shells have different builtins, though there will be a whole
>   lot of overlap in the basic set.

Now, I would like this to be experimented by yourself, so that you can understand why `read` is present as a shell builtin.

Normally, you couldn't do `strace` on shell builtins. However, there is a workaround for this as well. This is explained pretty neatly in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90711/is-it-possible-to-strace-the-builtin-commands-to-bash/90713#90713).

1. In the first shell, run the command as `stty -echo`.
2. Open another shell and run the command as `cat | strace bash >
   /dev/null`.
3. Now, the shell would be waiting for the user to type in the commands
   and there by when the user types the commands, you could see what
   happens in the system level as well.
4. When you give the above 3 commands, you could see that read has
   fewer system calls than the remaining 2 commands. I am not pasting
   the output from `strace` as it is pretty big.

Comment: Also the `read` builtin in `/bin/sh` pre-exists `head` and probably `sed`.

Comment: tl;dr: `read` is a builtin and skips the overhead and bookkeeping involved with starting a new process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use read `varname` only inside a shell script but other two you can use without writing shell script.

For example:

You can use `varname=$(head -1)` and `varname=$(sed 1q)` simply as a command in the terminal, but you have to provide your  argument as well i.e. which files topmost line you are referring i.e. `varnam=$(head -1 file1)`.

Comment: Of course you can use `read varname` outside a shell script.  Try it!  There are very few things you can do in a script that you can't do at a prompt in the "sh" family of shells (whether they are very useful is a different matter).