# strace not finding shell function with "Can't stat" error

Tags: shell, function, strace

I'm trying to call a self-defined function `funk_a` in `strace` but it doesn't seem to find it.
I confirmed that funk_a can be called by itself.
I appreciate any opinions.

```
$ source ./strace_sample.sh 
$ funk_a
Earth, Wind, Fire and Water
$ funk_b
Get on up
strace: Can't stat 'funk_a': No such file or directory

$ dpkg -p strace|grep Vers
Version: 4.8-1ubuntu5
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

strace_sample.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function funk_a {
  echo "Earth, Wind, Fire and Water"
}

function funk_b {
  echo "Get on up"
  strace -o trace_output.txt -c -Ttt funk_a
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is the output of `type funk_a`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strace` can only `strace` executable files.

`funk_a` is a function, a programming construct of the shell, not something you can execute.

The only thing `strace` could strace would be a new shell that evalutes the body of that function like:

```
strace -o trace_output.txt -Ttt bash -c "$(typeset -f funk_a); funk_a"
```

(I removed `-c` as it makes no sense with `-Ttt`).

But you'll then see all the system called made by `bash` to load and initialise (and after to clean-up and exit) in addition to that one `write` system call made by that `funk_a` function.

Or you could tell `strace` to trace the pid of the shell while it evaluates the `funk_a` function:

```
strace -o trace_output.txt -Ttt -p "$$" &
funk_a
kill "$!"
```

Though, by the time `strace` attaches to the PID of the shell, the shell could very well have finished interpreting the function. You could try some synchronisation like

```
strace -o trace_output.txt  -Ttt -p "$$" &
tail -F trace_output.txt | read # wait for some output in trace_output.txt

funk_a
kill "$!"
```

But even then depending on timing, `trace_output.txt` would include some of the system calls used interpret `tail|read`, or `kill` could kill `strace` before it has had the time to write the trace for the `echo` command to the output file.

A better approach could be to wrap the call to `funk_a` between two recognisable system calls like

```
strace -fo >(sed -n '1,\|open("///dev/null|d
                     \|open("/dev///null|q;p' > trace_output.txt
  ) -Ttt -p "$$" &
sleep 1 # give enough time for strace to start
exec 3<  ///dev/null # start signal
funk_a
exec 3< /dev///null # end signal
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out by myself after finding out in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90711/is-it-possible-to-strace-the-builtin-commands-to-bash?rq=1) that `strace` can only call an executable.

Changing my example above as follows worked.

util.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Earth, Wind, Fire and Water"
```

strace_sample.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

function funk_b {
  echo "Get on up"
  #strace -o funk_a.out -c -Ttt funk_a
  strace -o util.out -c -Ttt ./util.sh
}
```

Result

```
$ funk_b
Get on up
Earth, Wind, Fire and Water
$ more util.out 
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
  0.00    0.000000           0         7           read
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        27        18 open
:
```