# How are system commands like ls created?

Tags: shell, executable, architecture

I have some doubts regarding *nix.

- I don't know which type of executable file is `ls`, whether it is .sh
  or .ksh  or any other kind of system executable if it is, what
  is that?
- when I tried to see what is the source code of `ls` command looks like, it shows something unreadable, what method does *nix use to create these types of unreadable files and can I make my files similar to these files (like `ls` - unreadable).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a builtin command and one that is not?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not)

Comment: I think it's more related to the URL above than it's a dup.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can determine the nature of an executable in Unix using the `file` command and the `type` command.

#### type

You use `type` to determine an executable's location on disk like so:

```
$ type -a ls
ls is /usr/bin/ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

So I now know that `ls` is located here on my system in 2 locations:`/usr/bin/ls` & `/bin/ls`. Looking at those executables I can see they're identical:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ls /bin/ls
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 120232 Jan 20 05:11 /bin/ls
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 120232 Jan 20 05:11 /usr/bin/ls
```

**NOTE:** You can confirm they're identical beyond their sizes by using `cmp` or `diff`.

*with diff*

```
$ diff -s /usr/bin/ls /bin/ls
Files /usr/bin/ls and /bin/ls are identical
```

*with cmp*

```
$ cmp /usr/bin/ls /bin/ls
$
```

#### Using file

If I query them using the `file` command:

```
$ file /usr/bin/ls /bin/ls
/usr/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0x303f40e1c9349c4ec83e1f99c511640d48e3670f, stripped
/bin/ls:     ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0x303f40e1c9349c4ec83e1f99c511640d48e3670f, stripped
```

So these would be actual physical programs that have been compiled from C/C++. If they were shell scripts they'd typically present like this to `file`:

```
$ file somescript.bash 
somescript.bash: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

#### What's ELF?

[ELF is a file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), it is the output of a compiler such as `gcc`, which is used to compile C/C++ programs such as `ls`.

> In computing, the Executable and Linkable Format (ELF, formerly called Extensible Linking Format) is a common standard file format for executables, object code, shared libraries, and core dumps.

It typically will have one of the following extensions in the filename: none, .o, .so, .elf, .prx, .puff, .bin

Comment: @lgeorget - See this Q&A for tips on using type vs. which: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then. It's generally best to just use `type` anywhere you're tempted to use `which` or `whereis`.

Comment: Additionally, for GNU tools, the source code is freely available, start your search at http://www.gnu.org/software/

Comment: For the identical test, you really should be using something like `md5sum` or `sha1sum`, not just checking file sizes and times.

Comment: @Bob - Those files being identical had nothing to do with the Q so I showed a simple method. To compare the files I would've used a more apt tool such as cmp which is meant for comparing binary files. Also looking to see what package they're provided by would indicate if they're related or not. They're both part of `coreutils-8.21-13.fc19.x86_64` and I just know they're identical from 20 years of dealing with Red Hat releases.

Comment: @Bob - see updates for examples on comparing files.

Answer (score 9):

It is a binary executable (compiled into machine code, like most of the system). Shell scripts are more like "glue" to join parts together to quickly and flexibly create solutions out of existing stuff. That's the power of *nix.

You need the source code (c, sometimes c++, are the most common languages on *nix), not just the compiled executable. As it is open source, you can get the code for everything from online repositories (core utilities are usually from the gnu project). However, it's a bit tricky if you don't know how to use git or other version tracking systems.

Here is the ls.c file, if it helps:
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c

Comment: Oh and to clarify the question how to create binary applications: choose among countless programming languages (except for a couple that are interpreted or semi-interpreted, such as python, java, javascript,... which don't traditionally produce a standalone executable binary file). Then learn to use that language and how to compile it.