# CD with redirect to logger does not work

Tags: shell, pipe, cd-command, logger

On Linux, the following cd works fine so cds into tmp:

```
/ # cd /tmp
tmp #
```

But this does not work (stays at root, nothing appears in /var/log/messages). Why not?

```
/ # cd /tmp 2>&1 | /usr/bin/logger -t Test
/ #
```

I tried with stripping off this stderr redirect but that also did not work.

My goal is to redirect all output of my script to syslog, so also if I try to CD in a directory which does not exist/permission denied/etc.  Why is it not working and how to get this working?

A normal echo does print to syslog so that does work:

```
echo Test | /usr/bin/logger -t Test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pipe executes the producer (left-hand) process and the consumer (right-hand) process in parallel. Since there are two processes in parallel, at least one of them needs to be a child process of the main shell process, possibly both.

Most shells execute both sides of the pipe in subprocesses. ATT ksh and zsh execute the right-hand side in the original process.

The `cd` command changes the current shell process's current directory, so it [needs to be a builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not/11460#11460). Since the left-hand side of the pipe is executed in a subshell (a subprocess that's [forked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) from the shell process executing the script), the `cd` command only takes effect in the subshell. It works, but since the subshell exits immediately afterwards, it doesn't do anything useful. You can observe it with

```
{ cd /tmp; echo -n "left-hand side: "; pwd; } | 
{ cd /usr; echo -n "right-hand side: "; pwd; }
echo -n "parent: "; pwd
```

To log the output from your script, make a single pipeline that applies to your whole script.

```
main () {
  … # whole script goes here
}
main | logger
```