# How to change directory in shell script running in zsh shell

Tags: shell, zsh, cd-command

I am working on a shell script (shell used, its version and OS are below). The script runs commands in a local git repository/directory with has several tags. The script outputs some string from greping files in a certain directory which is selected based on the repository tag name.

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)
OS: System Version: macOS 13.6.3
+
using oh-my-zsh, https://ohmyz.sh/
```

The script changes directory (`cd` command) to the git local repository. Then it gets the tags in an array by `MY_ARRAY=($(git tag))`. Then for each repository tag it does `git checkout $my_tag --quiet`  to that tag. Then `cd` in one of the directories (directoryA) of the repository. Now it issues a `pwd` to check the working directory; the output is `/git-repository/directoryA`. At this moment the `pwd` output is as expected (`/git-repository/directoryA`). Now, while in `/git-repository/directoryA`, the script does `LIST_OF_SUBDIRECTORIES=($(ls -d */))` to get the array of the sub-directories of `directoryA`; the output is `LIST_OF_SUBDIRECTORIES is cw-events/ cw-metric-alarm/ eventbridge-scheduler/ msk/ secrets-manager/ ses/ sns-topic/ sqs/ ssm-params/ xlate/`. Now for each of this subdirectories (a `for` loop is used), the script SHOULD `cd` to a subdirectory in the array LIST_OF_SUBDIRECTORIES like this:

```
if echo "$my_tag" | grep -q -E "$MY_SUBDIRECTORY"; then
          echo "MY_SUBDIRECTORY is $MY_SUBDIRECTORY"
          set -x
          cd $MY_SUBDIRECTORY 2>&1 | tee -a log_file.txt
          set +x
          echo "PWD Working Directory is $(pwd)"
```

The output of `echo "MY_SUBDIRECTORY is $MY_SUBDIRECTORY"` is `MY_SUBDIRECTORY is cw-events/`; the if condition is true so I would expect for the script to `cd` in `cw-events/` but the above `echo "PWD Working Directory is $(pwd)"` is outputing `/git-repository/directoryA`.

 The script starts with `#!/bin/zsh`. Trying in `#!/bin/bash` I receive some errors.

 I found some other questions on https://blog.kubesimplify.com/how-to-change-directory-in-shell-scripts or [Script to change current directory (cd, pwd)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27139/script-to-change-current-directory-cd-pwd) but actually I do not want the directory to be changed in the parent shell but in the child shell.

 Why the script while in `/git-repository/directoryA` does not `cd` in `/git-repository/directoryA/subdirectory-of-A`?


Example of output:
The example I can give fast is the output of running the script:

```
FIRST-SUB-Directory is /git-repository/directoryA
LIST_OF_SUBDIRECTORIES is cw-events/ secrets-manager/ sqs/ ssm-params/
MY_SUBDIRECTORY is cw-events/
+/path/to/script/script.sh:44> cd cw-events/
+/path/to/script/script.sh:44> tee -a log_file.txt
+/path/to/script/script.sh:45> set +x
PWD Working Directory is /git-repository/directoryA
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please give us a _minimal_ example that reproduces the problem. We cannot really help debug code you don't show us, but you should be able to give a self-contained example that we can run to reproduce the issue.  SO have a nice guide for this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cmd1 | cmd2`, `cmd1` and `cmd2` run concurrently so they have to run in separate processes.

In many shells, both run in child processes even when they're builtin (such as `cd`). In zsh, like in ksh, `cmd2` would run in the current shell process if it was builtin, but `cmd1` always runs in a child process.

So in your `cd ... | tee ...`, `cd` runs in a child process and only changes the working directory of that short-lived child process.

zsh has `tee`'s functionality builtin though, so you shouldn't need to do that. You can do:

```
cd -- $MY_SUBDIRECTORY >&1 >> file.log 2>&2 2>> file.log || exit
```

When a fd is redirected more than once for writing, zsh redirects it instead via a pipe to a process performing a `tee`-like function in the background.

Here, we're redirecting fd 1 to what it's already redirected to (`>&1`) which normally would be a no-op but here expresses that we want to keep stdout going there, then redirect it in append mode to `file.log`. We do the same for fd 2 (stderr). That's another improvement over your `cd 2>&1 | tee` where `tee` would bundle the normal and error messages of `cd` on stdout.

Another improvement is that the exit status of `cd` is preserved. I've added a `|| exit` to make sure we don't carry on with the rest of the script if `cd` failed.

Note that `cd` only outputs something on stdout in things like `cd -`,`cd -2`, `cd +2` when navigating the directory stack which shouldn't be the case here, so you can get away with just `cd ... 2>&2 2>> file.log`.

Also note that neither that nor your `tee` approach would redirect the `xtrace` output. It goes to stderr, but it's not output by `cd` itself, you'd need to redirect a command group inside which `cd` is run to capture that xtrace output. Something like:

```
set -x # or set -o xtrace
{
  cd -- $MY_SUBDIRECTORY
} 2>&1 2>> file.log 
set +x
```

Rather than doing `set -x`, `set +x` where you'd see a trace for `set +x`, you can also enable the `xtrace` option locally in a function or anonymous function:

```
() {
  set -o localoptions -o xtrace
  cd -- $MY_SUBDIRECTORY
} 2>&2 2>> file.log
```

Or using a helper function:

```
trace() {
  set -o localoptions -o xtrace
  "$@"
} >&1 >> file.log 2>&2 2>> file.log

trace cd -- $MY_SUBDIRECTORY || exit
```

Or using `functions -t` which enables tracing for a function like in ksh:

```
trace() {
  "$@"
} >&1 >> file.log 2>&2 2>> file.log
functions -t trace

trace cd -- $MY_SUBDIRECTORY || exit
```

Beware `echo` expands escape sequences such as `\n`, `\uXXXX`, `\0123`... by default and accepts options. For it to output something as-is followed by a newline, you need:

```
echo -E - $something
```

Using `printf` (compatible with sh) or `print` (compatible with ksh and more versatile) is generally preferred though:

```
printf '%s\n' "$something"
print -r -- "$something"
```

Also note that `pwd` is a builtin command that prints the contents of `$PWD`, so `$(pwd)` is a bit pointless.

```
print -r "PWD Working Directory is $PWD"
```

Would make more sense.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. It is useful for me and I am sure it will be useful for others. PS: I cannot cast a vote (upvote) as I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 4):

This line is obviously wrong:

> ```
> cd $MY_SUBDIRECTORY 2>&1 | tee -a log_file.txt
> ```

The left-hand side of a pipe runs in a subshell, meaning that internal changes (variables, current directory, etc.) don't affect the main shell. See [CD with redirect to logger does not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219601/cd-with-redirect-to-logger-does-not-work/219677#219677) for more explanations and advice on logging. Although (except for `cd -`/`cd -2`/`cd +2`... when navigating the directory stack) `cd` doesn't emit output except if it fails, so logging its output is pointless anyway.

If you just change the line to `cd $MY_SUBDIRECTORY` (or better `cd -- $MY_SUBDIRECTORY`), changing the directory does work, at least for the part of the script you posted. If you still end up in the original directory later in the script, you might be doing something else that creates a subshell (in some part of the code that you haven't posted).

---

Beyond that, I don't see anything obviously wrong, but there are several things that are more complicated than they need to be. I recommend doing things in a simpler way, so that there's less risk of mistakes.

- You use `echo` *and* `set -x` *and* `| tee …` to log things. One is enough. `set -x` is fine in most circumstances. Piping to `tee` is tricky because it affects the behavior of the script (creating a subshell, changing file descriptors, hiding errors).
- `echo "$my_tag" | grep -q -E "$MY_SUBDIRECTORY"` checks whether the value of `my_tag`¹ contains the value of `MY_SUBDIRECTORY` as a substring, assuming that the value of `MY_SUBDIRECTORY` doesn't contain extended regular expression operators (such as `.` or `+` common in git tags). There's a simpler way to check that:

  ```
  if [[ $my_tag = *"$MY_SUBDIRECTORY"* ]]; then …
  ```
- `LIST_OF_SUBDIRECTORIES=($(ls -d */))` can be written just `LIST_OF_SUBDIRECTORIES=( *(-/) )`, using zsh's `/` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers), which allow filtering globs by file type and other characteristics. Here combined with `-` so the check of type is done after symlink resolution like `*/` does. This doesn't put a slash at the end of each element. You can use `…=( *(-/M) )` if you do want a slash, or for this special case of listing just directories you can use `…=( */ )`, but you probably don't actually need the slashes anyway. Add the `N` glob qualifier if you want to get an empty list rather than a fatal error if there are no subdirectories:

  ```
  LIST_OF_SUBDIRECTORIES=( *(N-/) )
  ```

---

<sup>¹ Strictly speaking, any line in the output of `echo "$my_tag"` as `grep` matches one line at a time and `echo` will also expand `\n` into a newline character (thankfully, git tags should be guaranteed not to contain backslashes)</sup>

Comment: I did the change proposed, that is from "cd $MY_SUBDIRECTORY 2>&1 | tee -a log_file.txt" to "cd $MY_SUBDIRECTORY" and all works as expected. Thank you for the link and the other detailed explanations.