# Understanding shell builtin commands

Tags: bash, shell, shell-builtin

In in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html), it's written that

```
Builtin commands are contained >>> within <<< the shell itself
```

Also, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not/11465#11465) answer states that

```
A built-in command is simply a command that the shell carries out itself,
instead of interpreting it as a request to load and run some
>>> other program <<<
```

When I run `compgen -b` on `bash 4.4`, I receive a list of all shell builtin commands. I see for example that `[` and `kill` are listed to be shell builtins. But their actual locations are:

```
/usr/bin/[
/bin/kill
```

I thought that being a `builtin` means that the command is compiled into the `/bin/bash` executable. So what's really confusing me: Please correct me, but how can a separate command be a `builtin`, when it is actually not part of the shell?

Comment: Some commands originally existed as separate utilities. Their presence now is for POSIX standard compliance, portability, as well as backwards compatibility. Shells implement some as built in for performance. There may be other reason, but that's about it without too much detail.

Comment: Another reason I could think of, is because some built-in commands are needed for shell specifically, like `exec` to manipulate file descriptors and `eval`  for evaluation of commands. They aren't needed as standalone commands

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The commands that are built into the shell are often built in because of the performance increase that this gives. Calling the *external* `printf`, for example, is slower than using the built in `printf`.

Since some utilities do not *need* to be built in, unless they are special, like `cd`, they are also provided as *external* utilities. This is so that scripts won't break if they are interpreted by a shell that does not provide a built in equivalent.

Some shell's built-ins also provide extensions to the external equivalent command.  Bash's `printf`, for example is able to do

```
$ printf -v message 'Hello %s' "world"
$ echo "$message"
Hello world
```

(print to a variable) which the external `/usr/bin/printf` simply wouldn't be able to do since it doesn't have access to the shell variables in the current shell session (and can't change them).

Built in utilities also does *not* have the restriction that their expanded command line has to be shorter than a certain length. Doing

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

is therefore safe if `printf` is a shell built-in command.  The restriction on the length of the command line comes from the `execve()` C library function used to execute an external command.  If the command line and the current environment is larger than `ARG_MAX` bytes (see `getconf ARG_MAX` in the shell), the call to `execve()` will fail.  If the utility is built into the shell, `execve()` does not have to be called.

Built in utilities take precedence over utilities found in `$PATH`. To disable a built-in command in `bash`, use e.g.

```
enable -n printf
```

---

There's a short list of utilities that *need* to be built into a shell (taken from the POSIX standard's [list of special built-ins](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14))

```
break
colon (:)
continue
dot (.)
eval
exec
exit
export
readonly
return
set
shift
times
trap
unset
```

These need to be built in since they directly manipulate the environment and program flow of the current shell session. An external utility would not be able to do that.

Interestingly, `cd` is not part of this list, but POSIX [says the following](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) about that:

> Since `cd` affects the current shell execution environment, it is always provided as a shell regular built-in. If it is called in a subshell or separate utility execution environment, such as one of the following:
>
> ```
> (cd /tmp)
> nohup cd
> find . -exec cd {} \;
> ```
>
> it does not affect the working directory of the caller's environment.

I'm therefore assuming that the "special" built-ins can't have external counterparts, while `cd` in theory could have (but it wouldn't do very much).

Comment: IIRC, `chdir`/`cd` were external binaries in very early Unices/pre-Unix before `fork` was introduced.

Comment: @Xophmeister Solaris 11.4 (beta) still has `/usr/bin/cd`, but it will not actually change the current working directory. Its manual says: `/usr/bin/cd` has no effect on the invoking process but can be used to determine whether or not a given directory can be set as the current directory.

Comment: Another, rather specific reason for builtins: builtin `kill` is also nice because it doesn't need to fork another process, good if you've hit your number of processes limit.

Answer (score 7):

You are (very understandably) confused by the fact that some builtins exist *both* as builtins *and* as external commands. So, while you're right that, for example, there is a `/bin/[` command, that doesn't mean that its "actual location" is in `/bin`.

Any easy way to test this is to run `type` with the `-a` switch which will show all available instances of a command. On my Arch system, that shows:

```
$ type -a [
[ is a shell builtin
[ is /sbin/[
[ is /usr/sbin/[
[ is /usr/bin/[
```

Note that `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/bin` are all symlinks pointing to `/usr/bin`, so there is only one external `[`:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/sbin /sbin /bin/
/usr/bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin
```

As you can see, `[` is both a builtin and an external command, and the same is true of various other shell builtins. However, that does not change the fact that they are also shell builtins, compiled into the shell itself.

Comment: why distro. provide seperate external command for a already existing internal command ? why do they duplicate ?

Comment: @linuxuser some of these utilities are required by POSIX, and you can't know whether the shell a user happens to be using will also provide a builtin. Don't think of them as internal command of the OS, they are only internal commands of the shell, and the shell can change.

Comment: I have 1 doubt now, if internal commands are provided by shell; then who provides external commands ? like i have observed many commands which are available as internal as well as external command, but i dint explicitly installed them; so who provides external command ? Distro provides them correct ?

Comment: @linuxuser depends on the command and the operating system. For example, on my Arch Linux, `/bin/printf` is installed by the `coreutils` package and `/bin/kill` by `util-linux`.

Comment: I am sorry but i am still unclear, which of above is provided by distro ? and what about the other which is not provided by distro then who provides it.

Comment: @linuxuser both `coreutils` and `util-linix` are packages provided by the distro. But please don't do this in comments. Either come into [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) or ask a new question.