# Why can't I see the manual for > but can see it for [?

Tags: bash, man, shell-builtin

I just did `man [` and it opened the manual.

Then I tried doing `man >` but I get this error:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

How is `>` different from `[`?

Comment: Altough `[` or `test` is a builtin it also exists as a separate command (`/bin/[`). `>` is  a redirection operator and is part of a shell implementation (does not exist as a separate command). Info about redirection operators can be consulted from the shell man page (e.g, bash, zsh, ksh, etc.).

Comment: I see. so how do I pull up documentation on `>` from with my terminal/command line?

Comment: so `>` is built in to `bash` or whatever shell I'm using. `[` is built into what?

Comment: Please see [What is the difference between a builtin command and one that is not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not).

Comment: `[` (or its alias `test`) has two implementations; it exists as a shell builtin and as a separate command. Whereas the redirection operators only exist as a builtin command.

Comment: Shell builtins do not have their own individual man pages l. They're documented in the respective shell man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, the command `man >` will invoke redirection rather than give you a man page for it.

Since `>` is a shell operator, you need to go to the man page for your shell, for example if you run `bash` you can use `man bash` and look for the section on 'REDIRECTION'. All the shell redirection operators will be listed there; they don't have their own `man` pages.

Comment: I hit `cmmd + f` and searched for `REDIRECTION` but wasn't able to find it. The search only worked if `REDIRECTION` was visible. Is that also happening for you? Is that expected or that's a bug?

Comment: My `MANPAGER` is `less` so I use forward slash `/` which will accept regex. For many distros this is the default `MANPAGER` but you can change it if you like.